# hover doesn't work for image?

Tags: jquery

I tried following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("image").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).append($("<span> ***</span>"));
      }, 
      function () {
        $(this).find("span:last").remove();
      }
    );

  });

<img  alt="" src="../../Content/Disp.gif" />
```

It did not work. even use $("img").  Does it mean hover not working for image?

Comment: Why are you trying to put span tags around it? Have you tried it on anything else to see if it works? Have you made sure your syntax is right and that you're actually selecting objects?

Comment: It should be IMG and an image element cannot have children appended to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in this code.
First the selector is not correct:
Wrong

```
$('image')
```

Correct

```
$('img')
```

Second, the img element cannot contains child elements as far as I know, so you cannot use the "find" command with it.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("img").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).append($("<span>***</span>"));
      }, 
      function () {
        $(this).find("span:last").remove(); // this not correct
      }
    );

  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$("img").each(function(){
    $(this).hover(function(){
        $(this).after("<span>Foobar</span>");
    }, function(){
        $(this).find("span:last").remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot append something to a selfclosing tag

```
<img src="lol.gif" alt="" /> is a self-closing tag.
You can only append to not self closing tags like <div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('img').hover(function(){
            $('span').html('Mouse over image'); 
        });
        $('img').mouseout(function(){
            $('span').html('Mouse not over image'); 
        });
    });
</script>  

<img  alt="" src="http://stackoverflow.com/content/img/so/logo.png" />
<span>Mouse not over image</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("img").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).after("<span> ***</span>");
      }, 
      function () {
        $(this).next().remove();
      }
    );
  });
</script>

<img alt="" src="../../Content/Disp.gif" />
```

Please do read api.jquery.com, it's a rather quick read through as the library is kind of tiny.